# Android: Use onclicklistener to initiate email intent

Tags: android

I was given the following to use to create an email form from the user. The app gathers 3 strings, but I don't know how to incorporate the submit button with this email code.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a `Button` in your layout:

```
<ParentLayout [...]>

   <Button [....] android:id="@+id/myButton"/>

</ParentLayour />
```

Create an object of your `Button`:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

Set an `OnClickListner`:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Do the email stuff in here.
             }
         });)
```

Comment: where does the create object line go? (relative to the activity)

Comment: In the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: would you be willing to let me email you the activity file so you could look at it?